# Transforming simple sql to "access sql"

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

i need some help to transform sql code to sql access code,my code is:

```
SELECT `HOTEL`.`NAME_H`,`ROOM`.`NUMBER_R`,`ROOM`.`FLOOR_R`
FROM HOTEL, ROOM
WHERE `HOTEL`.`CODE_H`=`ROOM`.`CODE_H`
AND `HOTEL`.`TOWN_H`=`Athens`
AND (`HOTEL`.`CODE_H`,`ROOM`.`NUMBER_R`)
NOT IN (SELECT `CODE_H`,`NUMBER_R` FROM RESERVATION)
```

its not running in access,I don’t know how to use not in in ms,any ideas? I have a problem and with another one,my code is:

```
SELECT `ΟFFER`.`CODE_O`,`HOTEL`.`NAME_H`,`ROOMTYPE`.`NAME_RT`,MIN(`OFFER`.`PRICE_O`)
FROM OFFER,HOTEL,ROOMTYPE
WHERE `OFFER`.`CODE_H`=`HOTEL`.`CODE_H`
AND `OFFER`.`CODE_RT`=`ROOMTYPE`.`CODE_RT`
GROUP BY `CODE_O`
```

Comment: How about you give the full error messages you get? And add which position in the Access SQL is marked as error.

Comment: `NOT IN` is valid in Access SQL but you must align it to one column not multiple. As for second query, for group by queries all non-aggregated columns must be referenced in `GROUP BY` clause. Sadly, MySQL allows such a query where it fails for most RDMS's depending on only_full_group_by setting.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using originally? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT h.NAME_H, r.NUMBER_R, r.FLOOR_R
FROM HOTEL as h INNER JOIN
     ROOM as r
     ON h.code_h = r.code_h
WHERE h.TOWN_H = "Athens" AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM RESERVATION as r
                  WHERE h.CODE_H = r.CODE_H AND
                        h.NUMBER_R = r.NUMBER_R
                 );
```

In fact, this should work in most databases.

Comment: its not working in ms access 2007,it asks me for a parameter.

Comment: Any ideas about the second?

Comment: @Nick.P. . . . The backticks were an oversight.  The single quotes were another problem . . . MS Access uses double quotes for strings.